# How to reference the default UIView to animate in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift

I have 2 view controllers: "MapScreenVC" and "PullUpMenuVC"; When you tap a button on the "MapScreenVC", the "PullUpMenuVC" should appear, pulling up from the bottom. Them problem I am having is that in regards to the default UIView for the "PullUpMenuVC", **any visual changes I make in storyboards do not show up.**

That said, when I call my prepareBackgroundView() function, the view changes accordingly upon build.

How can I edit the view in storyboards but still animate the view in code? I feel like I have a misunderstanding of how views are referenced from the storyboard. Is the view that I am animating not the default view of the view controller, which is the same view that should be visually edited in the storyboard?

My "PullUpMenuVC" class:

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    prepareBackgroundView()
}

func prepareBackgroundView()
{
    view.backgroundColor = .white
    view.tintColor = defaultTint
}

override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)

    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.35) { [weak self] in
        let frame = self?.view.frame
        let yComponent = UIScreen.main.bounds.height * 1
        self?.view.frame = CGRect(0, yComponent, frame!.width, frame!.height)
    }
```

This is a screenshot of my storyboard:
[image: screenshot of stotyboard]

I should also point out that I have connected the "PullUpMenuVC" class to the view controller in my storyboard.

Comment: Offtopic: Notice that 1. the [weak self] block isn't needed and 2. If for some reason self is nil, the system will crash because you force unwrap frame.height/width.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have misunderstood how this is usually done in iOS and Xcode. From your description above I understand you want to do something that looks like a Modal View Presentation.

If you use the default modal view presentation iOS offers for doing that transition between ViewController, you will not have to implement the animations yourself. In fact you can do the whole think in the Storyboard by just hooking up the segues.

I am attaching some reading material that might help you. 
https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/PresentingaViewController.html

https://www.raywenderlich.com/462-storyboards-tutorial-for-ios-part-2

Custom transition if you need it.
https://www.raywenderlich.com/359-ios-animation-tutorial-custom-view-controller-presentation-transitions

Hope the above help.